# Worker Thread process settings for Asp.net core application with Quartz.net scheduler on nginx server

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, quartz.net

I have developed asp.net core web application with scheduler quartz.net and deployed the same scheduler sample on nginx server. It is working fine.

Whenever we deploy Quartz.net on IIS, we set Start Mode = AlwaysRunning in General tab and Idle Time-out(minutes) = 0 in Process Model. So that it will not stop when App is idle.

Is there any similar settings required to be done on nginx? If yes, what changes are needed to be done?

Answer (score 0):

iis application pool will recycle by default. You should change it in iis application pool advanced settings